# Having an issue with div layout positioning

Tags: html, css

I have been fighting with this for a while, I'm trying to make a specific setup and I've gotten so frustrated at it I've resorted to using tables (very bad).  So what I'm trying to do:

5 divs.

- 1 on the right side of the screen, ~120px width, 100% of the page
  height
- 1 in the bottom left of the page, 120px height, 120px width
- 1 above that one, 120 width, all remaining height
- in the middle between these 1 div on the top, with height of 80px,
  and width filling between the other divs
- and the last div in the middle taking up all remaining space

Any solution I have come up with required at least some JS, which I am doing everything I can to avoid, so I am looking for a purely CSS3 solution!

Comment: Please provide the HTML and relevant CSS you have so far in addition to the way it looks with js

Comment: Twitter bootstrap can help you a lot when it comes to the layout of your pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using HTML5 and CSS3 using display flex

Something I quickly mocked up http://codepen.io/tom-maton/pen/mbJAs

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="top-left-column">Top left</div>

    <div class="bottom-left-column"> bottom left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="center-top-column">Top Center</div>

    <div class="center-bottom-column">Bottom center</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-column">Right Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid #333;

}

.main {  
  border: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
}

.top-left-column {
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  width: 120px;
}

.bottom-left-column {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.center-top-column {
  height: 80px;
}

.center-bottom-column {
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}

.right-column {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 120px;
}
```

You just need to check your browser support beforehand as flex not supported in IE8/9